# What is the best way to show 2 listviews in android?

Tags: android, listview

So im doing a project wherein it will contain checkboxes (listview) that resembles tasks, and below that would be a comments section, (another listview). How could I possibly achieve this?

Comment: You could split the screen into two listView's simply by using LinearLayouts.

But personally I'd recommend going for a Dialog View for the comments section, something along the lines of what Facebook does in it's android app.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve that by just putting two ListViews with equal weights in a layout. (I also put some labels to separate the ListViews)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Tasks"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Comments"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Will this layout act like a scroll view?

Comment: Each ListView will scroll independently

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 Linearlayouts inside the root layout (here: linearlayout).
set weight of both to 0.5
The listviews in both have heigth of match_parent
- Done

Comment: so if they have varying heights because of different number of items in them, it will look normal like the whole screen will act like a scrollview?